# HTTP 401.3 - Access denied on Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am trying to run a website from IIS with Widows Authentication. The authentication window pops up and I enter my credentials thrice and then I get this message on page

"You are not authorized to view this page

HTTP 401.3 - Access denied by ACL on resource
Internet Information Services"

Config
IIS 5.1
Windows XP - Windows XP SP3

I think I have everything needed in my cofig..

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<identity impersonate="true"/>
<authorization>
  <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

I even tried this link

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;896861

But didn't change anything.

Please Help.

Comment: check the application pool user permissions on the application folder. your user might not have windows permissions to access the folder.

Comment: That did it!!! I can't believe it.. Phew!!! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check the application pool user permissions on the application folder. your user might not have windows permissions to access the folder